# JPA entity graphs and pagination

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, pagination, entitygraph

In my current project we have multiple search pages in the system where we fetch a lot of data from the database to be shown in a large table element in the UI. We're using JPA for data access (our provider is Hibernate). The data for most of the pages is gathered from multiple database tables - around 10 in many cases - including some aggregate data from OneToMany relationships (e.g. "number of associated entities of type X"). In order to improve performance, we're using result set pagination with `TypedQuery.setFirstResult()` and `TypedQuery.setMaxResults()` to lazy-load additional rows from the database as the user scrolls the table. As the searches are very dynamic, we're using the JPA CriteriaQuery API to build the queries. However, we're currently somewhat suffering from the N+1 SELECT problem. It's pretty bad in some cases actually, as we might be iterating through 3 levels of nested OneToMany relationships, where on each level the data is lazy-loaded. We can't really declare those collections as eager loaded in the entity mappings, as we're only interested in them in some of our pages. I.e. we might fetch data from the same table in several different pages, but we're showing different data from the table and from different associated tables in different pages.

In order to alleviate this, we started experimenting with JPA entity graphs, and they seem to help a lot with the N+1 SELECT problem. However, when you use entity graphs, Hibernate apparently applies the pagination in-memory. I can somewhat understand why it does that, but this behavior negates a lot (if not all) of the benefits of the entity graphs in many cases. When we didn't use entity graphs, we could load data without applying any WHERE restrictions (i.e. considering the whole table as the result set), no matter how many millions of rows the table had, as only a very limited amount of rows were actually fetched due to the pagination. Now that the pagination is done in-memory, Hibernate basically fetches the whole database table (plus all relationships defined in the entity graph), and then applies the pagination in-memory, throwing the rest of the rows away. Not good.

So the question is, **is there an efficient way to apply both pagination and entity graphs with JPA (Hibernate)?** If JPA does not offer a solution to this, Hibernate-specific extensions are also acceptable. If that's not possible either, what are the other alternatives? Using database Views? Views would be a bit cumbersome, as we support several database vendors. Creating all of the necessary views for different vendors would increase development effort quite a bit.

Another idea I've had would be to apply both the entity graphs and pagination as we currently do, and simply not trigger any queries if they would return too many rows. I already need to do COUNT queries to get the lazy-loading of rows to work properly in the UI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your problem but we faced something similar: We have paged lists of entities that may contain data from multiple joined entities. Those lists might be sorted and filtered (some of those sorts/filters have to be applied in memory due missing capabilities in the dbms but that's just a side note) and the paging should be applied afterwards.

Keeping all that data in memory doesn't work well so we took the following approach (there might be better/more standard ones):

1. Use a query to load the primary keys (simple longs in our case) of the main entities. Join only what is needed for sorting and filtering to make the query as simple as possible.


   In our case the query would actually load more data to apply sorts and filters in memory where necessary but that data is released asap and only the primary keys are kept.
2. When displaying a specific page we extract the corresponding primary keys for a page and use a second query to load everything that is to be displayed on that page. This second query might contain more joins and thus be more complex and slower than the one in step 1 but since we only load data for that page the actual burden on the system is quite low.

Comment: Your case sounds very similar to ours (we also have a bunch of dynamic filters and sorting rules that need to be applied before the paging). I actually considered trying a similar solution as you suggest, but thought that it would be too inefficient. But apparently it isn't? So in step 2, you define an IN condition in the query with the primary keys of the main entities? I'm a bit concerned that I might encounter [HHH-9230](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9230) if I do that (we're still using Hibernate 4.x). Then again, you never know until you try  :)

Comment: I tried out the approach you suggested, and it seems to work pretty well. At least my initial impression is that it's a lot faster than Hibernate's in-memory pagination, but I haven't done any concrete measurements yet. I did run into [HHH-9374](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9374) when running certain queries, though, but I'm hoping that upgrading Hibernate will solve that. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @MarkusYrjölä I'm glad to hear it works. We're using 4.x as well so it should work (we're not using entity graphs though). One thing I'd like to add: since the second query's where condition might result in quite a big in-statement we normally split that and issue multiple queries. From our experience there a sweet spot/region where "smaller" queries/results result in a performance boost that outweighs the penalty you get by using multiple queries instead of one. The sweet spot may vary but a size of 250-500 worked quite well for us.