# JPQL Query for page of children and join fetch of grandchildren throws exception query specified join fetching

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpql

I have entities:

```java
class Parent {
  ...
  @OneToMany(Fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @OrderBy("id")
  private List<Child>  children;
}


class Child{
  ...
  @OneToMany(Fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @OrderBy("id")
  private List<GrandChild> grandChildren;
}

class GrandChild {
  ...
}
```

I want to query for paginated childs and also fetch grand childrens. I also filter childrens by name, but I don't think it's important. I have such JPQL query:

```java
@Query("select c " +
       "from Parent p " +
       "inner join p.children c " +
       "inner join fetch c.grandchildren g " +
       "where p = :parent and " +
       "c.childName like concat(:childName,'%')")
    Page<Expense> findBy(@Param("parent") Parent parent, @Param("childName")String childName, Pageable pageable);
```

And during starting spring boot application exception is thrown:

> query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list

Message is straightforward, however i can't add parent to select statement cause i want only children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that when you want to get page of data you can't use `join fetch` so according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764696/jpa-entity-graphs-and-pagination). I have created two methods in JpaRepository.

1. Method to retrieve page of child ids
2. Method to retrieve children with fetched grandchildre.

This is how code looks like after that:

```java
@Query("select c.id " +
  "from Parent p " +
  "inner join p.children c " +
  "where p = :parent and " +
  "c.childrenName like concat(:childrenName,'%')")
Page<Long> findIdsBy(@Param("parent") Parent parent,
  @Param("childrenName") String childrenName,
  Pageable pageable);

@Query("from Children c join fetch c.grandChildren where c.id in :ids")
List<Children> getChildrenByIdWithGrandChildren(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);
```

Answer (score 2):

c.grandchildren is missing the **alias e**

```
@Query("select e " +
       "from Parent p " +
       "inner join p.children c " +
       "inner join fetch c.grandchildren e" +
       "where p = :parent and " +
       "c.childName like concat(:childName,'%')")
    Page<Expense> findBy(@Param("parent") Parent parent, @Param("childName")String childName, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault i query for children not grandchildren, I have edited my question.